# Parsing with python and saving as csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a webpage with python and beautifulsoup package. I have the console to print out the parse results before saving. When parsing in the cmd console, every data in each column is printed fine. But when saving into csv, the row jumps to the next column when encountering a comma. The columns before encountering the comma are all fine.  I'm using MS Professional Plus 2010 to execute the csv data.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


import requests
from lxml import html
import re

filename = "eng.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers ="abc, def, cdf\n"
f.write(headers)
url = ""

r = requests.get(url, headers = {"User-Agent":"Chrome/56.0.2924.87"})

tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

patternAB= r'ab\s=\s"(.*?)"'

script = tree.xpath('//script[contains(., "ab")]/text()')[0]
eng_name=re.search(patternAB, script).group(1)

script1 = tree.xpath('//script[contains(., "ab")]/text()')[2]
regions=re.search(patternAB, script1).group(1)
......#I use the above code repeatedly with different indexes

f.write(eng_name + ";" + regions + ";" + origins + ";" + "\n")
#I also tried "," as connector but to no avail.
f.close()
```

Any idea what went wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the sample data you are receiving in cmd prompt. Also use csv module as it takes care of lot things like escaping, etc.

Comment: If you edited to the question to include the `url`, we would be able to recreate your problem.